# How to add updated object information back into a specific index in an array of objects? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing, event-listener

I have a practice app that is supposed to accept new information and put the information into an array of objects. It also has the option to edit specific data in the array. Everything works perfectly until I try and re-insert the new information back to where the old information was stored inside the array. The problem is occurring in the editObj function. I removed all the bad code I knew existed and left what I know works.

```
//HTML elements
var table = document.querySelector('#list');
var main = document.querySelector('#main');
var form = document.querySelector('#form');
var userInput = document.querySelector('#userInput');
var addBtn = document.querySelector('#add');
var saveBtn = document.querySelector('#save');

//Object array
var Assignments = [ ];

//main function

var mainView = function() { 
  table.innerHTML = '';
  for(i = 0; i < Assignments.length; i++){
      //elements
      var row = document.createElement('tr');
      var data = document.createElement('td');
      var data2 = document.createElement('td');
      var data3 = document.createElement('td');
      var edit = document.createElement('td');
      var remove = document.createElement('td');
      var editBtn = document.createElement('button');
      var deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
      //rendering
      data.innerHTML = Assignments[i].name;
      data2.innerHTML = Assignments[i].possible;
      data3.innerHTML = Assignments[i].earned;    
      //innerText
      editBtn.innerText = "Edit";
      deleteBtn.innerText = "Delete";
      //set attributes
      editBtn.setAttribute('index',i);
      deleteBtn.setAttribute('index',i);
      //appending
      edit.appendChild(editBtn);
      remove.appendChild(deleteBtn);
      row.appendChild(data);
      row.appendChild(data2);
      row.appendChild(data3);
      row.appendChild(edit);
      row.appendChild(remove);
      table.appendChild(row);
      //event listeners
      editBtn.addEventListener('click', editObj);
      deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteObj);
      //unhide table
      main.style.display = '';
  }
};

//add form

var addObj = function() {
    main.style.display = 'none';
    form.style.display = '';
};

var saveObj = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var itmObj = {};
    var name = 'name';
    var pP = 'possible';
    var pE = 'earned';
    itmObj[name] = userInput.name.value;
    itmObj[pP] = userInput.pP.value;
    itmObj[pE] = userInput.pE.value;
    Assignments.push(itmObj);
    console.log(Assignments);
    form.style.display = 'none';
    mainView();
};

//editing functions

var editObj = function(e) {
    main.style.display = 'none';
    form.style.display = '';
    saveBtn.style.display = 'none';
    newSaveBtn.style.display = '';
    //get object
    var editing = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('index');
    userInput.name.value = Assignments[editing].name;
    userInput.pP.value = Assignments[editing].possible;
    userInput.pE.value = Assignments[editing].earned;
    //remove original from array
  Assignments.splice(editing, 1);
    //add new data to array


};

//delete

var deleteObj = function(e) {
    var removing = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('index');
    Assignments.splice(removing, 1);
    mainView();
};

//event listeners


addBtn.addEventListener('click', addObj);
userInput.addEventListener('submit', saveObj);
```

Assuming nothing is wrong with the current code... How do I get the new updated information back to the previous indexed value?

This was one of the ways that I tried and the eventListener will not fire on the new button:

```
var editObj = function(e) {
    main.style.display = 'none';
    form.style.display = '';
    saveBtn.style.display = 'none';
    //get object
    var editing = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('index');
    userInput.name.value = Assignments[editing].name;
    userInput.pP.value = Assignments[editing].possible;
    userInput.pE.value = Assignments[editing].earned;
    //remove original from array
  Assignments.splice(editing, 1);
    //add new data to array
     var editBtn = document.createElement('button');
     editBtn.innerText = 'Save New';
     form.appendChild(editBtn);
     editBtn.addEventListener('click', editTest);

//test editing

var editTest = function(e){
    console.log(editing);
    var newObj = {};
    var newName = 'name';
    var newpP = 'possible';
    var newpE = 'earned';
    newObj[newName] = userInput.name.value;
    newObj[newpP] = userInput.pP.value;
    newObj[newpE] = userInput.pE.value;
    Assignments.splice(editing, 0, newObj);
    form.style.display = 'none';
    form.removeChild(editBtn);
    saveBtn.style.display = '';
    mainView();
};

};
```

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you reduce your example to the **minimum** that displays the issue, explain what you expect to happen and also describe what does happen, including any error messages. You should also supply some minimal HTML to go with the example.

Comment: I added my most recent attempt. No errors, just a problem with the eventListner not attaching to the button.

Comment: `'onclick'` should be `'click'`.

Comment: Hmm, changed that and it still will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Fixed it. Turns out the editObj and editTest functions needed to be combined. Here is the working code:

```
var editObj = function(e) {
    main.style.display = 'none';
    form.style.display = '';
    saveBtn.style.display = 'none';
    //get object
    var editing = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('index');
    userInput.name.value = Assignments[editing].name;
    userInput.pP.value = Assignments[editing].possible;
    userInput.pE.value = Assignments[editing].earned;
    //remove original from array
  Assignments.splice(editing, 1);
    //add new data to array
     var editBtn = document.createElement('button');
     editBtn.innerText = 'Save New';
     form.appendChild(editBtn);
     editBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(editing);
    var newObj = {};
    var newName = 'name';
    var newpP = 'possible';
    var newpE = 'earned';
    newObj[newName] = userInput.name.value;
    newObj[newpP] = userInput.pP.value;
    newObj[newpE] = userInput.pE.value;
    Assignments.splice(editing, 0, newObj);
    form.style.display = 'none';
    form.removeChild(editBtn);
    saveBtn.style.display = '';
    mainView();
});
```